# POST /token 400 (Bad Request) with ember-cli and ember-simple-auth

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-cli

I just setup the example from https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth-example using Cloud9 and I get a 400 Bad Request error when I try to login.

I'm pretty sure this is due to fact that Cloud9 only opens port 80 (as referenced in this note from http://log.simplabs.com/post/90339547725/using-ember-simple-auth-with-ember-cli:

> As the OAuth 2.0 authenticator would by default use the same domain
>   and port to send the authentication requests to that the Ember.js is
>   loaded from you need to configure it to use `http://localhost:3000`
>   instead.

Unfortunately I don't know how I might work around this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add the host to the whitelist in the config:

```
window.ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  crossOriginWhitelist: ['http://some.other.domain:1234']
}
```

More info in the [Cross Origin Authorization section of the docs](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth)

Comment: Thanks man, unfortunately I switched over to Angular and can't test this, but I appreciate you providing a potential solution - if someone else says that it works, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: No worries.. I had this exact same problem the other day :)           good luck with Angular!